# Add component in a JPanel subclass

Tags: java, swing, inheritance, jpanel, composition

I want to create a JPanel subclass thats holds some JLabels. I started to write my code but I immediatly find a big problem. Component added to the JPanel subclass are not visible (or they are not added to JPanel I don' t kano). This is the code of the JPanel Subclass:

```
public class ClientDetails extends JPanel
{

    private JLabel nameAndSurname = new JLabel ("Name & Surname");
    private JLabel company = new JLabel ("Company");

    private JPanel topPanel = new JPanel ();

    public ClientDetails ()
    {

        this.setBackground(Color.white);
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        topPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(topPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        topPanel.add(nameAndSurname);
        topPanel.add(company);

        this.add(topPanel,BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

    }

}
```

Comment: 1) Don't extend components, just keep a reference to them.  2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Sorry but why not extends that? It' s better in my case to have a ready component to holds my label to not make the code complicated

Comment: See [Composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).

Comment: I' m going to read this article. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to

- put the JPanel in a top level container (like a JFrame)
- call pack() on it so the LayoutManager finds room for your stuff

.

```
public  class Test extends JPanel {

    private JLabel nameAndSurname = new JLabel ("Name & Surname");
    private JLabel company = new JLabel ("Company");

    private JPanel topPanel = new JPanel ();
    JFrame frame;

    public Test()
    {
        this.setBackground(Color.white);
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        topPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(topPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        topPanel.add(nameAndSurname);
        topPanel.add(company);

        this.add(topPanel,BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

        frame = new JFrame("test");
        frame.add(this);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I use this custom JPanel in a JFrame that has also a lot of other components so I can't create and pack it in my JPanel subclass. How can I fix that? thanks!

Comment: are you re packing and repainting the containing JFrame after you have added the JPanel ?

Comment: The JPanel is added with the NetBeans IDE so I think that NetBeans do it like all the other components